# Group headers lost when filtering a grouped list

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, grouping

I have a custom view formatting a list of sites, grouped by a heading that contains a combination of data (calculated field.) When SOME of my users apply a filter - the grouping is lost and we're left with a stack of cards for the sites - no grouping context. Anyone know why the group heading get lost? NOTE:  this is only happening for a few people (but of course, they're the most active users.)

[image: Example1]

This is what is SHOULD look like.  The customer names/contact have been blurred.
[image: Example2]

The field used in the group is a calculated field of Customer and Contact so that I can get both values into the heading.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue is somehow related to the "Offline Client Availability" setting. Setting this flag to "No" seems to solve this issue of display wonkiness.

Don't know why --- just know that it does.